# Создание файла c уже созданным контентом, который бы назывался как сессия

Tags: php

У меня есть файл `proxy.txt`, и есть сессия `$_SESSION['id_user'])` and `isset($_SESSION['login_user']`.

Как реализовать, чтобы при заходе на `giveproxy.php` парсился контент из `proxy.txt`, создавался файл в дерикторию `download`, который бы назывался как сессия пользователя (`iduserlogin_user`), и чтобы к названию приписывалась дата парсинга (15:40 к примеру), и пользователя перенаправляло на новосозданный файл? ФАЙЛ ДОЛЖЕН БЫТЬ БЕЗ РАСШИРЕНИЯ.

Comment: Что значит `перенаправляло на новосозданный файл`?

Comment: Пример:
Зашел rootuser на giveproxy.php, в директории www/site/dowload/ создается файл с название rootuser16:10 через 1 секунду rootuser перенаправляет на новосозданный файл

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://site.com';
    $fname = '/download/'.$_SESSION['id_user'].date('H:i');
    file_put_contents($fname, 'test-data');
    Header('Location: '.$url.$fname);
```

Comment: Можешь мне поподробнее расписать что за что отвечает.

Comment: Возможно вы не правильно поняли меня. Я хочу что бы при заходе на giveproxy.php(в нем будет код, который вы мне предложите) создавался файл в директории www/mysite/download/ с ником и временем(как пример взять сессию), а в этом файле будет текст из файла proxy.txt, который будет лежать в корне сайта.

Comment: @user198445 ответ по моему исчерпывающий, остальное противоречит правилам сайта, так как за вас работу делать никто не будет, за что вы сейчас и получаете минусы

Comment: @user198445 не код **КОТОРЫЙ ВЫ МНЕ ПРЕДЛОЖИТЕ**, а код **КОТОРЫЙ Я ДЕЛАЛ НО У МЕНЯ НЕ ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ**

Comment: Алексей, не стоит настолько быть жестоким... Я в php 3-ий день... Я ищу помощи у людей, которые это решают за пару секунд...

Comment: @user198445 Так для начала изучите язык и прочтите документацию. Пробуйте делать сами, А если что-то не получается - обращайтесь. В ином случае получается работа за вас - а не помощь профессионалов. И таким образом вы ничему не научитесь, если всюду всю работу за вас будут делать...... что ж сразу не с написания своей ОС начали то?

Comment: @user198445, а какая конкретно из 4-х строк вам непонятна?

Comment: @Grundy почти все непонятно, мне бы разжевать все методом 
'$url = 'http://site.com'; // - Ссылка на сайт'И т.п.
Извините что нарушаю правила, просто написал авторизацию, регистрацию, проверку на авторизацию, а это создать не могу.

Comment: @user198445 [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php), [operators.string](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php), [function.header](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php)

Comment: Если я заполню поля, то вот этот пример будет действовать как я и описал?
 
Пример: Зашел rootuser на giveproxy.php, в директории www/site/dowload/ создается файл с название rootuser16:10 через 1 секунду rootuser перенаправляет на новосозданный файл с контентом, который спарсился с proxy.txt